# How to create conditional vnet based on address space that I give in terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

**Objective**:  Trying to create azure vnet where address space differ based on environment

**Code I am trying:**

**Variable.tf:**

```
   variable "vnet_address_space" {
    type = map(any)
    default = {
        "Dev"  = ["xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/20"]
        "Stage" = ["xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/20"]
        "Prod" = ["xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/24","xx.xx.0.0/20"]
    }
}
```

**Main.tf:** (updated)

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = var.hub_vnet_name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg[0].name
  for_each = {for k,v in var.vnet_address_space: k=>v if k == "Dev"}
  address_space       =  var.vnet_address_space.Dev
  dns_servers         = var.dns_servers
  tags     = {
    environment = "${var.env}"
    costcentre = "14500"
  }
  dynamic "ddos_protection_plan" {
    for_each = local.if_ddos_enabled

    content {
      id     = azurerm_network_ddos_protection_plan.ddos[0].id
      enable = false
    }
  }
}
```

However It did not work as intended

**Error I get:**

```
on main.tf line 85, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet":
│   85:   address_space       = [var.vnet_address_space]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.vnet_address_space is a map of dynamic, known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "address_space": element 0: string required.
```

Comment: Is this your exact code? There are odd syntax errors like a missing `{`, and a typo `address_spac`.

Comment: Updated code and different trail in original post

Comment: Does it work if you use type of `map(list(string))`?

Comment: Atleast now, it pass through that error after map(list(string)) but now I face issue with subnet as it was complaining hat vnet has for each etc.. will work on it nd let u know if any progress... thanks for guidance